# How can I immediately break from searching through directory recursively once desired file is found?

Tags: node.js, typescript, recursion, fs

I'm recursively searching through a directory structure for a file with a specific name. I want to break as soon as the first instance of that file is found. How can I accomplish this? Currently it's continuing to parse through the rest of the files even after it's found an instance of the file i'm looking for.

```
async function walkDir(dir: string, callback: Function) {
  for (const f of await fs.readdir(dir)) {
    const dirPath = path.join(dir, f);
    if ((await fs.stat(dirPath)).isDirectory())
      walkDir(dirPath, callback);
    else if (callback(path.join(dir, f)))
      return;
  }

let foundFile = false;
await walkDir(startDir, function (f: string) {
  console.log(f);
  if (path.basename(f) === 'manifest.xml') {
    foundFile = true;
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest option is probably to return `true`/`false` from the callback and from `walkDir` if the value was found.

```
async function walkDir(dir: string, callback: (path: string) => boolean): Promise<boolean> {
    for (const f of await fs.readdir(dir)) {
        const dirPath = path.join(dir, f);
        if ((await fs.stat(dirPath)).isDirectory()) {
            if (await walkDir(dirPath, callback)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        else if (callback(path.join(dir, f))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


var args= { dir: "" };
(async function () {
    let foundFile = false;
    await walkDir(args.dir, function (f: string) {
        console.log(f);
        if (path.basename(f) === 'manifest.xml') {
            foundFile = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
})();
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAECkFcGcBdQCYFMBmBLAdm2aD2HpRZdQBbAQwGskjCALcgB0YE8AoDc0paR8gYxopCAbzagJoJAA9GuAE7xk-ADbl5QyBn458oDeQQI08gBTH5ALlBx5mAOYBKawAV5uUmmhIAPLYcA2gC6AHzikjJyiohIquqa2roYNrDksOYm1v4YTq7unt4+IqBeACImscTyLKbOoABGuLgqSOTJAL5h7WwcXDx8gqB8sHSgYpJSsgpKsWoaoChaOnjJAFa4mKYAdDsWWbB2OcF12fbhEpHTMXHzi4krDeTenNzbu5kph-bH+19s3WwnixtAslklQAB3cgqSjlMx7T4OAA0oH40JU9QElGspmGdF+DkcoAAvCEGk0Wm06m4PF5fI1mq0MGTxpIUApQKZ+Pg4AtQLgUKByFDsAtoFsDEYTBl5I4iayJhJuQQlCYXGlRsShhqtutNhYUShHABuc6KtCC0ymYXkUXCLZwNIy9UjOVbMoVHQKGpysZmxWSC2cm2iqEwuHOjUotEqDFY30KgNJjSwSDyZIHSBIf1J7pJ0B5pNIFTeEqWmNx-iUXE6vUYGWGuXynMBlNpjPyLOm-OFiS9-RIVPphbQ7ymgFsABu6iF8ns0C1iYRACJl-9TdboMD+KD7npan6Ji14OytAgAGJoFokkclpDdyQh+Bh2HS9TzrYG3fLfcoAk5Zt82VaBGS2FRcHsUwjQfAMgxrEYtkxZ4+igoliXQ0AAHIKCwFAeFgLZpFIFRMMA-M2VwM9L2vLVM3vFtFTbYc6JgxV+wmJjkhQUd6ImdoTX+RxamNIA)

This can also simplify the call for the use-case you have in your sample code:

```
let foundFile = await walkDir(args.dir, f => path.basename(f) === 'manifest.xml');
```